# How to configure beanio to ignore certain chars in a flat file

Tags: java, flat-file, bean-io

I am currently working on a legacy application that gets its data via flat files. To read and write flat files beanio is used and the records are defined via annotations. My Problem is that the specification of one of the flat files demands that from index 20 to 26(not the end of the record) blanks are used to reserve space for future purposes.

How can I tell Beanio via annotations that at these positions are blanks it has to ignore?

Comment: You will probably want to use [this](http://beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html#FixedLengthFields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to define a `@Field` of length 7 to consume these spaces?

```
@Field(at = 20, length = 7, lazy = true, trim = true)
private String spaces;
```

The `lazy=true` and `trim=true` parts should make this field/property be `null` at all times.